# AWS - Steps/Consideration for migrating to latest generation of ec2 from an older generation

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops, infrastructure

I am looking at upgrading from older generation ec2 to the latest generation for example m3.medium to m5.large. Are there any steps or considerations that need to be made when making this change? I couldn't find any documentation that is linux specific, only windows specific: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/migrating-latest-types.html.

If anybody could help me I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Some thing to consider would be drivers if you have old linux. M5 has [enhanced networking](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/enhanced-networking-ena.html#ena-requirements) and [NVMe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/nvme-ebs-volumes.html#install-nvme-driver) for example. But I think a good way to test the m5 would be to create AMI of you current m3 instance, and evaluate it  on some testing m5 instance.

Comment: Thank you very much @marcin. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upgrade the instance type on AWS I usually follow this official doc
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html

However it also depends on the complexity of application running on your instance viz. just an apache server or a database? To handle that situation as @Marcin mentioned, always start with AMI of your instance and try doing any change before applying directly on production instances. 
[screenshot from the official doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYTAU.png)

Comment: Thank you very much vik. Again greatly appreciated. I am new to how AWS works so I am getting my head around all of this stuff.

Comment: Thanks @codemonkey1010, Feel free to accept this answer if it answers your question. You can do so by clicking the Tick mark/Check mark underneath the vote button.